# How to solve this type of error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"?

Tags: python, k-means

I'm using k-means to cluster the images, which contains 66 font images. For each image, we use the coefficients projected on the first 40 principal components as the feature vector. This image clustering project comes from the book "Programming Computer Vision with Python".

But it occurred with "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "**/demo1.py", line 16, in 
immatrix = array([array(Image.open(im)).flatten() for im in imlist], 'f')
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
"

The codes are as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PCV.tools import imtools
import pickle
from scipy import *
from pylab import *
from PIL import Image
from scipy.cluster.vq import *
from PCV.tools import pca

# Uses sparse pca codepath.
imlist = imtools.get_imlist('./a_selected_thumbs/')

im = array(Image.open(imlist[0]))  # open one image to get the size
m, n = im.shape[:2]  # get the size of the images
imnbr = len(imlist)  # get the number of images
print("The number of images is %d" % imnbr)

# Create matrix to store all flattened images
immatrix = array([array(Image.open(imname)).flatten() for imname in imlist], 'f')

# PCA
V, S, immean = pca.pca(immatrix)

#f = open('./a_pca_modes.pkl', 'wb')
f = open('./a_pca_modes.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(immean,f)
pickle.dump(V,f)
f.close()


# get list of images
imlist = imtools.get_imlist('./a_selected_thumbs/')
imnbr = len(imlist)

# load model file
with open('./a_pca_modes.pkl','rb') as f:
    immean = pickle.load(f)
    V = pickle.load(f)
# create matrix to store all flattened images
immatrix = array([array(Image.open(im)).flatten() for im in imlist],'f')

# project on the 40 first PCs
immean = immean.flatten()
projected = array([dot(V[:40],immatrix[i]-immean) for i in range(imnbr)])

# k-means
projected = whiten(projected)
centroids,distortion = kmeans(projected,4)
code,distance = vq(projected,centroids)

# plot clusters
for k in range(4):
    ind = where(code==k)[0]
    figure()
    gray()
    for i in range(minimum(len(ind),40)):
        subplot(4,10,i+1)
        imshow(immatrix[ind[i]].reshape((25,25)))
        axis('off')
show()
```

Is it because of the size of the image? If I change the image to my own(500*300, and the size of the images are different), the above error will be reported, and the image data that comes with the book(25*25 pixels) will not report an error.

Comment: The pixels are 500*300 and 25*25.

Comment: Can you put here of how the out put of array([array(Image.open(im)).flatten() for im in imlist], 'f'?

Comment: Basically, add .values or .values[0] after immatrix variable the code is trying to assign.